# Prove that a certain subset of $\mathbb{R}$ possesses a lower bound

Tags: real-analysis

I have the set $A=\{x \in R: \exists m \in \mathbb{Z} : 4x>m+3\}$. This set is not superiorly bounded because I can see it as the set of $\left\{x \in R:x>\frac{m+3}{4}\right\}$ and $\frac{m+3}{4} \in \mathbb{Q}$. But is it inferiorly bounded?

Comment: Isn't $A=\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any $x\in\mathbb R$, you have $4x>m+3$ if you take $m\leq\lfloor 4x-3\rfloor$. So $A=\mathbb R$.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Given any real number, there is an integer smaller than it. So given $x$, there exists an integer $m$ smaller than $4x-3$.